# Basic client-server socket based C communication

Tags: c, sockets, server, client, virtualbox

it's been a week since i've been introduced to sockets. I'm trying to figure out how to realize a simple communication between 2 device (in my case 2 debian 8 virtual machine, both running on virtualbox) I'm running something like this:

```
/****************** SERVER CODE ****************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  int welcomeSocket, newSocket;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
  socklen_t addr_size;

  /*---- Create the socket. The three arguments are: ----*/
  /* 1) Internet domain 2) Stream socket 3) Default protocol (TCP in this case) */
  welcomeSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  /*---- Configure settings of the server address struct ----*/
  /* Address family = Internet */
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  /* Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order */
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);
  /* Set IP address to localhost */
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  /* Set all bits of the padding field to 0 */
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

  /*---- Bind the address struct to the socket ----*/
  bind(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

  /*---- Listen on the socket, with 5 max connection requests queued ----*/
  if(listen(welcomeSocket,5)==0)
    printf("Listening\n");
  else
    printf("Error\n");

  /*---- Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection ----*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
  newSocket = accept(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);

  /*---- Send message to the socket of the incoming connection ----*/
  strcpy(buffer,"Hello World\n");
  send(newSocket,buffer,13,0);

  return 0;
}



/****************** CLIENT CODE ****************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  int clientSocket;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  socklen_t addr_size;

  /*---- Create the socket. The three arguments are: ----*/
  /* 1) Internet domain 2) Stream socket 3) Default protocol (TCP in this case) */
  clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  /*---- Configure settings of the server address struct ----*/
  /* Address family = Internet */
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  /* Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order */
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);
  /* Set IP address to localhost */
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  /* Set all bits of the padding field to 0 */
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

  /*---- Connect the socket to the server using the address struct ----*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;
  connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addr_size);

  /*---- Read the message from the server into the buffer ----*/
  recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);

  /*---- Print the received message ----*/
  printf("Data received: %s",buffer);   

  return 0;
}
```

It seems like the code is fine but i have issue on connection. Should i change something into `/etc/network/interfaces` or other? I really cannot understand where is the issue.

Client:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.2.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.2.2
```

The server is the same, simply got `address 10.0.2.100`

Maybe there is even something wrong with virtualbox settings..
Thanks for your help

Comment: Both your client and server are using localhost.  Have you tried running both the client and server code on the same machine to do some initial debugging?

Comment: Please check the error return values of your library and system calls, and use `perror` if you do not get a successful result.

Comment: @LukeSmith what do you exactly mean for both machines using localhost? you mean both referring to 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: 'recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);' of all the system calls to discard the result of, you chose that as one:(   You MUST correctly and completely handle the results from system calls, especially that one.  Oh - and the other usual suspect too: 'printf("Data received: %s",buffer);' call of 'printf("%s..' on a buffer that is not guaranteed NUL terminated.  Where to put the NUL? See first point.  Don't forget to leave space for it, eg. by reading 1023, or declaring your buffer as 1025, just in case.

Comment: @ducajack yes, both refer to `127.0.0.1`.  Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but I cannot see any `10.0.2.XXX` addresses in you code.

Comment: @LukeSmith yes there is not.. how do i have to change that address( 127.0.0.1 ) in both client and server? Thanks

Comment: @ducajack If I was you I would probably leave things as they are for now and run both back to back in the same VM for your initial debugging.  This willbe an easier environment to work through any other bugs first.

Comment: @MartinJames: His payload includes the `\0`.

Comment: @ducajack Then once you've got things going on one machine change `127.00.1` to `INADDR_ANY` on the server and to `10.0.2.100` on the client and try it on the machines as you specify in your original question.

Comment: @jxh it may well do, but since recv(), if it receives anything, is not guaranteed to load the buffer with any more than one byte, that does not matter.

Comment: @MartinJames: You are correct, the code doesn't verify all the data has been received.